# Prevent overwrite of existing shortcuts

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-catalina

When assigning custom keyboard shortcuts (in Catalina 10.15.4), is it possible to avoid conflicts so that existing (system) shortcuts aren't accidentally overwritten?

I was thinking something along the lines of how Visual Studio allows lookups of existing shortcut assignments by inputing arbitrary key combinations.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app called [CheatSheet](https://mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/) that can display the frontmost app's entire shortcut suite.

As far as I'm aware there's no way to display every single shortcut, for every single app, system-wide.

There are also a colossal number of built-in shortcuts, listed at Apple KB - [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/HT201236) which I expect no-one will ever remember all of ;)

Comment: After seeing a few "quick lists" for shortcuts I started to suspect there were many, and is why I was hoping for a Visual Studio style lookup. Thanks for links, will check out.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to read the shortcut file/table from a shell script or an API (this is my first Mac so I know virtually nothing about them, other than that they're really nice and super cool)?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, sorry. I'm a user not a coder. Chat up the guys from CheatSheet, or poke StackOverflow where the actual coders hang out.